# Eclipse uninstallation

Tags: eclipse

I have installed two different version of eclipse- one from software and another from eclipse' website. Now I want to uninstall the eclipse which I downloaded from its website. How can I do it?

Comment: Eclipse doesn't install in this sense. You unzip it and it just lives in the the files system in that one folder where you placed it. Deleting it is all you need to do.

Answer (score 2):

To remove eclipse(Installed from software center), go to terminal and use following commands,

> sudo apt-get autoremove eclipse
>
> rm -r ~/.eclipse/

for eclipse downloaded, just delete the folder.